# Does Greater Restoration affect all conditions that specify that as an ending condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Take the situation where someone is under the influence of Modify Memory, Feeblemind and Geas (or similar spells that specify Greater Restoration as an ending condition).

Do all conditions end in one casting of Greater Restoration, or is one casting needed for each condition?

Comment: Please ask your bonus question as a separate question. There's no stigma against many, good questions here and our experience is that separately posting them yields better Q&A all around.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Only one effect is removed per casting

#### Greater restoration is intended to remove only one condition per casting

> You imbue a creature you touch with positive energy to undo **a debilitating effect**.

The description makes it clear that only one effect is removed at a time. So you would need a separate casting for each effect.

> You can reduce the target's Exhaustion level by **one,** or end **one** of the following effects on the target.

You can't even remove multiple levels of exhaustion with one casting. The spell is simply intended to work one at a time.

#### None of the specifics of the individual spells implies that they override this

Feeblemind

> The spell can also be ended by Greater Restoration, heal or wish.

Geas

> A Remove Curse, Greater Restoration, or wish spell also ends it.

Modify Memory

> A Remove Curse or Greater Restoration spell cast on the target restores the creature's true memory.

All these mean is that the spells can be removed by greater restoration, not that they are automatically removed when it is cast on the afflicted creature for any reason.