# Can either flavor of Restoration remove the Frightened condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions

The characters in our party got a minor boon that allows us to cast either Minor or Major Restoration on ourselves once as a bonus action.

We're about to face off against an enemy that has Frightful Presence. Basically, they can cause mass fear with a high DC.

So the question is: **Is Frightened a condition that either of these spells would remove?**

#### [Lesser Restoration](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Lesser%20Restoration#content)

> You touch a creature and can end either one disease or one condition afflicting it. The condition can be Blinded, Deafened, Paralyzed, or Poisoned.

#### [Greater restoration](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Greater%20Restoration#content)

> You imbue a creature you touch with positive energy to undo a debilitating effect. You can reduce the target's Exhaustion level by one, or end one of the following effects on the target.
> • One effect that Charmed or Petrified the target
> • One curse, including the target's Attunement to a cursed magic item
> • Any reduction to one of the target's Ability Scores
> • One effect reducing the target's hit point maximum

No explicit mention of Frightened in either one and the [Fear](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Fear#h-Fear) spell (the closest thing to Frightful Presence) makes no mention of Restoration as a clearing effect (unlike other spells like [Geas](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Geas#h-Geas), [Feeblemind](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spells:Feeblemind#h-Feeblemind), etc.)

So according to RAW, the answer would appear to be **No**, but this just seems wrong. Why would these spells remove more serious effects but not cover a much more minor one?

Am I missing some detail, or is Fear actually a special effect that completely bypasses Restoration or does it fall under the *"undo a debilitating effect"* wording of Greater Restoration?

Comment: Why does this "just seem wrong"?

Comment: If I had a choice of being Frightened, Blinded, Deafened, Paralyzed, Poisoned, Charmed or Petrified... 

I'd pick Frightened every time.

It's short-term and relatively minor compared to the rest.

Comment: @SumofeDpi: That doesn't explain why you think it's "wrong" that neither *restoration* spell removes the frightened condition.

Comment: Added the why to the question. Why bypass a lesser debilitating effect in favor of some major ones?

Comment: Semi-related: [Does Greater Restoration also end the effects cured by Lesser Restoration?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128116/does-greater-restoration-also-end-the-effects-cured-by-lesser-restoration), [Does Greater Restoration affect all conditions that specify that as an ending condition?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116157/does-greater-restoration-affect-all-conditions-that-specify-that-as-an-ending-co)

Comment: @SumofeDpi provided it's only temporary, I would rather go for *Deafened* than *Frightened* (in combat). As far as I know, it has no impact whatsoever on the game, aside from roleplaying-wise. Unlike in previous editions, it doesn't impact spellcasting negatively.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. While I've previously written an answer to it, looking at it again it seems to me that the question is mistitled - currently, it's "can either flavor of Restoration remove the Frightened condition". The body, however, basically says "no, not by RAW" (which is obvious / and asks "Why not?". That, in turn, makes this a question asking for designer intent, which is considered off-topic.

Comment: No worries. Happy to have a definite answer, even if it is a disappointing "Nope."

Comment: But to be pedantic, I wrote the answer "_appears_ to be no." and followed up by asking If I were missing a detail that would change the answer to "yes", which is not the same as saying "_no, not by RAW_"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No, otherwise it would be mentioned by the spells' descriptions.

That being said, I believe the reason why it's not mentioned are **the spells' intended usages / their themes**.

*Lesser Restoration* allows you to remove the following conditions:

> disease, [...] blinded, deafened, paralyzed, or poisoned

All of them are **physical conditions**, leading me to believe that the intent of the spell is to be your all-rounder spell for minor illnesses etc. *Frightened* is not a physical condition, therefore it doesn't fit the theme.

Moving on to *Greater Restoration*, it can remove the following effects:

> - One level of exhaustion
> - One effect that charmed or petrified the target
> - One curse, including the target’s attunement to a cursed magic item
> - Any reduction to one of the target’s ability scores
> - One effect reducing the target’s hit point maximum

It removes major detrimental effects, and once again, they are **all physical effects (and curses), aside from the *Charmed*** condition. In my opinion, it would be reasonable to include *Frightened* alongside *Charmed*, but since *Charmed* can be way more impactful than being *Frightened* (in one case, you run away, in the other, you might fight for the opposing team), that's probably why they chose *Charmed* instead of *Frightened*.

In addition to the previous paragraphs, **there are spells that *do* help against the *Frightened* condition** (sometimes limited to against specific types), just not the *Restoration* spells:

- *Protection from Evil and Good*: immune against being *Frightened* (and other effects) by aberrations, celestials, elementals, fey, fiends, and undead, and advantage on saving throws for existing effects.
- *Aura of Purity*: advantage on saves against *Frightened* (and other effects)
- *Heroism*: immunity against the *Frightened* condition
- *Heroes Feast*: immunity against the *Frightened* condition
- *Calm Emotions*: can suppress the *Frightened* condition for its duration, i.e. up to 1 minute. Effect resumes afterwards, unless the duration has run out.

There are probably a few others that I failed to find.

Answer (score 6):

## No, neither *restoration* spell removes the frightened condition

As you've correctly observed, neither *lesser restoration* nor *greater restoration* has any effect on the frightened condition.

That said, I'm pretty sure every official fear effect describes a duration, and/or an opportunity to repeat the save to end the effect.

For instance, the [*fear*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72743/can-you-choose-a-different-ability-for-hex-when-changing-its-target?rq=1) spell says:

> If the creature ends its turn in a location where it doesn't have line of sight to you, the creature can make a Wisdom saving throw. On a successful save, the spell ends for that creature.

And a [sea hag](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sea-hag)'s Horrific Appearance trait says:

> A creature can repeat the saving throw at the end of each of its turns, with disadvantage if the hag is within line of sight, ending the effect on itself on a success. If a creature's saving throw is successful or the effect ends for it, the creature is immune to the hag's Horrific Appearance for the next 24 hours.
>
> Unless the target is surprised or the revelation of the hag's true form is sudden, the target can avert its eyes and avoid making the initial saving throw. Until the start of its next turn, a creature that averts its eyes has disadvantage on attack rolls against the hag.

And the Ancient White Dragon's Frightful Presence says:

> A creature can repeat the saving throw at the end of each of its turns, ending the effect on itself on a success. If a creature's saving throw is successful or the effect ends for it, the creature is immune to the dragon's Frightful Presence for the next 24 hours.

The likely reason the *restoration* spells don't affect the frightened condition is that the condition rarely lasts long enough (e.g. out of combat) to necessitate being cured by such a spell.